# CakePHP continue session outside cake

Tags: session, cakephp

I'm trying to continue the CakePHP session outside the application.

The CakePHP session config:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'timeout' => 10080, // 1 week,
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_httponly' => 1,
    )
));
```

cakephp_webroot/test_session.php:

```
<?php
session_name("CAKEPHP");
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

test session.php should output the cake session, but it is not working. I've verified the cookie CAKEPHP is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `cake` defaults for session handling, they are not compatible with the PHP defaults (available as `php` for the `defaults` option).

The `cake` configuration uses a custom save path and enforces cookie usage.

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../Datasource/CakeSession.php#L600-L612](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.4/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php#L600-L612)**

```
// ...
'cake' => array(
    'cookie' => 'CAKEPHP',
    'timeout' => 240,
    'ini' => array(
        'session.use_trans_sid' => 0,
        'url_rewriter.tags' => '',
        'session.serialize_handler' => 'php',
        'session.use_cookies' => 1,
        'session.cookie_path' => self::$path,
        'session.save_path' => TMP . 'sessions',
        'session.save_handler' => 'files'
    )
),
// ...
```

So either configure your external scripts session usage the same as the `cake` defaults, or use the `php` defaults instead, and control things via your PHP ini configuration.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > Sessions > Built-in Session handlers & configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration)**
- **http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php**